# Finding roots of a degree-3 polynomial with $n$ variables

Tags: polynomials

I Have a polynomial of the form
$$P(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{ij\ell}a_{ij\ell}x_ix_jx_\ell+\sum_{ij}b_{ij\ell}x_ix_j+\sum_i c_i x_i +d.$$
I want to find whether the polynomial has root in $[0,1]^n$. I know of at least one root in this area, denoted as $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, but want to know if there is more than one.
Hence I want to solve the problem
$$P(\boldsymbol{x})=0,\;\text{s.t }    \boldsymbol{x}\in[0,1]^n$$
I don't need to find ALL the roots in the area, it is enough that I'll find one since I'm only interested in the question whether
$\boldsymbol{x}_0$ is the unique solution in this range or not.
How can I solve this?

Comment: if exists, probably not unique $P(x)=0$ is one equation, but you have $n$ variables.

Comment: First, I want to know if it is unique in a specific range (the [0,1]^n square). Second, the existing root is also exactly the point where the gradient is zero, so it could be unique I think, right?

Comment: Why should the gradient be zero at the root? You are not looking for an extreme point.

Comment: Its just is, in my specific case. That is why I'm not sure if it is a unique root in the range or not. If the gradient wasn't zero then I would have an infinite number of solutions in the range.

Comment: You have managed to confuse me. Are you looking for a solution of $P(x)=0$ or a solution for $\nabla P(x)=0$?

Comment: The first. But it so happens that the solution I already know of, is also a solution to the second.

Comment: I think that typical root finding algorithms don't work very well near a root that is also an extremum, but you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms .

Comment: Thanks! I indeed thought of trying Newton's Method, but I can't find an example for this algorithm when $x$ is a vector and not a scalar. Do you maybe have a pointer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Systems_of_equations